# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^{1/n} - 1}{1/n} = \ln a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a>1$. If someone could give me an extended prove of that result using only sequence sequences, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an alternative: l'hopital's rule. By the way, I suppose your limit is $n\to\infty?$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By definition $$a^{1/n}=e^{\ln(a)/n}=1+\frac{\ln(a)}n+\frac12\left(\frac{\ln(a)}{n}\right)^2+\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $$a^{1/n}-1=t$$ then we have $$\frac{1}{n}=\frac{\ln(1+t)}{\ln(a)}$$
then we have
$$\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(1+t)^{1/t}}$$
and for $t$ tends to $0$ we get $$\ln(a)$$ since $$\ln(1+t)^{1/t}$$ tends to $\ln(e)=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a^{\frac1n} - 1}{\frac1n} = \ln a \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}} - 1}{\frac{\ln a}{n}} \to \ln a \cdot 1=\ln a$$